# Output power for resitive load half controlled rectifier

Tags: rectifier

[image: Half-controlled recitifer]

I have calculated power as V^2 / R so 140.1 x 140.1 / 200. It was marked incorrect. I can't see what I'm missing here?

[image: schematic]

Comment: "Power" output isn't DC values?

Comment: Where is this question from? I'd like to know of it's from a marked test you're currently taking or not.

Comment: You're missing the angle. There's an integral as a function of \$\alpha\$.

Comment: To be sure that it is half ..., what is your schematic.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the behavior in two configurations of controlled rectifiers.
Half-wave ... and full-wave. EE&O.
"I" have also calculated various quantities. What is valid?
Remember and write ... the power "definition", if more than one ...

[image]

[image]